# Expand div to fill rest of browser window and center content

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve a particular layout for a website I'm working on, but I'm not sure how to about it. The layout will look like this:

[image]

The header has nothing special about it. The footer has `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0px`. The main body content needs to be centred vertically within the space from the bottom of the header down to the top of the footer. If the window height is adjusted, the body content should remain centred between these two points. Also note that the website will be responsive, but only from 960px up to about 1600px (so the minimum width it will ever be is 960px).

My only idea on how to achieve this is to have the div containing the body content somehow automatically expand to always be the full height from the bottom of the header down to the bottom of the browser window (and then add some padding at the bottom to account for the footer), then use `display: table` on this containing div, and use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on a child div.

Are there any other (preferably CSS-only) ways I could potentially do this? If not, how can I get the containing div for the body content expand to always be the full height from the bottom of the header down to the bottom of the browser window?

Comment: The solution you proposed will work, CSS table-cells are a good idea.  What happens if the window height gets small enough and the content starts to overflow, you would need a scroll bar on the content block.  Is the header fixed similar to the footer?

Comment: Yes, that definitely would be needed. Not sure if I can make that happen with just CSS or if some JavaScript will be needed. I'm also not sure how to get the body content's containing div to expand to the full height from the header to the bottom of the browser window in order to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Can you say something about the header, fixed height, fixed position or not?

Comment: Added a few extra details to the OP. The header is just positioned statically. If it needs to be fixed height in order for a particular solution to work, this would probably be possible, but it would be better if it didn't have to be fixed height.

Comment: This is called "sticky footer" (so that you know what to google)

Comment: I know what a sticky footer is, and how to implement one. My question is more concerned with having a particular div expand to full height as specified, and then vertically centring content within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution, for a header with a fixed height.

Your HTML needs to have the following pattern:

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">Content...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: beige;
}
.main-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/aGTKs/

It is possible to adapt this to a header of flexible height.

The `.main-wrap` container defines the space between the header and footer.

The `.container` block uses `display: table` and inherits the height from `.main-wrap`.

Finally, `.content` uses `display: table-cell`, which allows you to use `vertical-align: middle` (default value) to center the content vertically.

You need to set the height of `body` and `html`to be 100% to capture the height of the view port.

Comment: Before I try to implement this solution, is there a way to make it so that a scrollbar will appear when the height of the browser window isn't big enough to fit all of the body content? Here's an update to your jsFiddle with some lorem ipsum text, you can see if you reduce the size of the Result window, it's not really working as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/aGTKs/3/

Comment: Add `overflow: auto` to `.main-wrap`, I updated the post and fiddle.

Comment: One of the problems is that it is possible to make the window height small enough so that the content is completely hidden behind the footer. I tried a few variations and could not work around that problem.  For the moment, this may be the best that I can do.  When I think about it, if you have a fixed height fixed-position footer, you can always shrink the window height to that of the footer, and then you loose your content; I don't see a way to prevent this without using some JavaScript/jQuery methods or a media query to check for a small window size.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it by doing `{position: absolute; bottom: 0}` !